# react-native-gesture-handler is not updating value after movement finish

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-gesture-handler

I am using react-native-gesture-handler with react-native-reanimated. When movement is finished, I am trying to update some values which is not working. Here is the code:

```
            <PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={Animated.event([{
                nativeEvent: ({ translationX: x, translationY: y, state }) =>
                    block([
                        set(this.touchY, y),
                        cond(eq(state, State.END), [
                            set(this.height, add(this.height, y)),
                            set(this.translateY, add(this.translateY, y)),
                            set(this.touchY, new Value(0))
                          ]
                        )
                    ])
                }])}
             >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `onGestureEvent` doesn't fire when the state ends. What you're looking for is `onHandlerStateChange`. This is copy-pasted from a component I written a while ago.

```js
<PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={gestureHandler} onHandlerStateChange={gestureHandler}>
```

If you need to handle that event **only** when the state ends I would suggest simply using
`onHandlerStateChange`. Otherwise, would be a good idea to extract that `Animated.event(...)` to a separate constant and pass it to both `onGestureEvent` and `onHandlerStateChange`.

Comment: Is it possible to add some sort of checks in the onGestureFunciton? Or can we only use the event directly? See this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64330969/stop-dragging-after-a-limit-has-reached